# 100% height active link within a td - Responsive table design - IE

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am currently making a responsive table with html and css. I have it working perfectly in all browsers except for IE, and this is any version of IE including 10. I only need it to work for IE 8,9 and 10.

The TD's within the table are 100% height in all browsers but the active links within the TD's do not work in IE. If you see the js fiddle below you can see the current day's background colour should fill the TD and it does not in IE. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is much appreciated. Below is a link to the js fiddle, the table styles and the active link within the td of the table

```
.compact_month_view {
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.day_cell a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtHFK/

Answer (score 0):

Give height for td - .compact_month_view td

Comment: cant set a height in pixels as it is a responsive design. Cant set in % because the amount of rows changes depending on the month